# identifying event on arc of circle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, automatic-ref-counting, mouseevent

I am a new user of  html5 and using canvas  to draw circle for one of my application. I have drawn  several arcs to form a circle. it works fine. However my problem is that i want to associate a separate mouse event for each of the arc.

I goggled and found KinteticJS may be useful. I wish to know is there any other way that could be used to attached mouse event for every arc  i created using the canvas. Please note i have used just one canvas there is no ghost canvas and I do not wish to use SVG. Below is the line of the code i used:

```
context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", doMouseDown(evt), false);
```

regards
nad

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quick answer is: **No, but...**

**No:**

Canvas does not "remember" anything drawn on itself--drawings are just color pixels added to the canvas.  Canvas doesn't know the position of your arc and can't hit-test to see if the mousdown is inside that arc.

**but...you can use math**

You can use math to test if any point is inside the circle.

If any x/y is inside the outer radius of a circle and *not inside* the inner radius, then x/y is in the arc.

Given centerX,centerY,outerRadius,innerRadius:

Test if x,y is inside the outer radius:

```
var dx=testX-centerX;
var dy=testY-centerY;
var isInsideOuterRadius=(dx*dx+dy*dy<outerRadius*outerRadius);
```

Test if x,y is *not inside* the inner radius:

```
var isInsideInnerRadius=(dx*dx+dy*dy<innerRadius*innerRadius);
```

So
   if( isInsideOuterRadius && !isInsideInnerRadius){ alert("x/y is in your arc"); }

**If you want to get fancy:**

If you "remember" the arc for canvas, then canvas has a hit-test for that arc.

Context.isPointInStroke will test if an X/Y is located inside the most recently drawn path.  If that most recent path is your arc, you can hit-test your arc.

For example, if you draw this arc:

```
context.beginPath();
context.arc(100,100,50,0,Math.PI);
```

You can hit-test that arc by supplying isPointInStroke with your mouse coordinates:

```
if(context.isPointInStroke(mouseX,mouseY)){
    console.log("The mouse is INSIDE the arc");
}else{
    console.log("The mouse is OUTSIDE the arc");
}
```

To test multiple arcs,

1. Define one arc ( do context.arc without context.stroke )
2. Test that arc with isPointInStroke
3. Do #1 with the next arc

**Except IE :(**

isPointInStroke will work in Chrome and Firefox but won't yet work in Internet Explorer.

**Alternatively for IE:**

You can define a path around the outside of your arc and then use isPointInPath to test if your mouse is inside that path.

**[ Update: and example ]**

[image]

Here's a Fiddle (must view with Chrome or FF -- IE won't work):

http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/DsPL7/

Here's example code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.lineWidth=15;

    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    var PI2=Math.PI*2;

    // create some test data objects
    var arcs=[];

    //outer arcs
    arcs.push({cx:100, cy:100, radius:75, start:0, end: PI2*.33, color:"red"});
    arcs.push({cx:100, cy:100, radius:75, start:PI2*.33, end: PI2*.66, color:"green"});
    arcs.push({cx:100, cy:100, radius:75, start:PI2*.66, end: PI2, color:"blue"});
    // inner arcs
    arcs.push({cx:100, cy:100, radius:45, start:0, end: PI2*.55, color:"purple"});
    arcs.push({cx:100, cy:100, radius:45, start:PI2*.55, end: PI2*.75, color:"orange"});
    arcs.push({cx:100, cy:100, radius:45, start:PI2*.75, end: PI2, color:"maroon"});

    // visibly draw all arcs 

    for(var i=0;i<arcs.length;i++){
        defineArc(arcs[i]);
        context.strokeStyle=arcs[i].color;
        context.stroke();
    }

    // define BUT NOT VISIBLY DRAW an arc

    function defineArc(arc){
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(arc.cx,arc.cy,arc.radius,arc.start,arc.end);
    }

    // handle mousemove events

    function handleMouseMove(e){

        // get mouse position
        mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
        mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

        // reset the results box to invisible
        context.clearRect(225,30,20,20);

        // hit-test each arc
        for(var i=0;i<arcs.length;i++){

            // define one arc
            defineArc(arcs[i]);

            // test that one arc
            // if "hit" fill the results box with that arc's color
            if(context.isPointInStroke(mouseX,mouseY)){
                context.fillStyle=arcs[i].color;
                context.fillRect(225,30,20,20);
                return;
            }

        }

    }

    // listen for mousemoves

    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <h4>Move mouse over any arc</h4>
    <h4>When mouse is over arc, that color rect will appear</h4>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks marke, however what if i have made several arc say for example four arcs in a circle, as you mentioned that Context.isPointInStroke  will just work for most updated created arc.
regards

Comment: To hit-test any of your 4 arcs, you can redefine one arc (context.arc...but no need for context.stroke) and then do the isPointInStroke.  If you want to test a complete circle, I have added an alternative "math" answer.

Comment: thanks , but i did nt understand it. let me explain me you what I am doing. actually I am drawing a concentric circles each divided with number of arcs , i am using it for data visulization of huge data. so once i draw all the circles and all the arcs on it, how will i be able to test. following is the code that I am using:

Comment: for (var j= 0;j<24; j++)
    
 {
    
var value=Math.floor((Math.random()*maxenegry)+0)   
r = Math.floor((255 * value) / maxenegry),
g = Math.floor((255 * (maxenegry - value)) / maxenegry)
b=0.6*maxenegry
var  colorname= "rgba(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ","+ 0.9 + ")";
 context.beginPath();
 context.fillText(colorname.toString(),100,j*60);
 context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
context.stroke();
startAngle = endAngle;
endAngle = (15+(j+1)*15)*Math.PI/180;
}

Comment: I added an example to my answer which hit-tests multiple concentric circle-arcs using isPointInStroke.  Good luck with your project! :)

Comment: thanks. last night when i left office with ur comments in my mind ,  i got what u wanted to say and devloped, and this morning ur when i saw ur example it was more or less liek what i thought.Thank you very much for ur help

Comment: Hi its me again :) while the code works fine and do as required but now there is slightly problem. after creating all this arc which for checking the mouse coordinates, if wish to draw a circle using fill or stroke than i get many circles due to already created acrs. is there any way i can also draw a single arc such that my already drawn arcs (as we discussed last time) is not visible. regards and thanks for ur time.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand :\  So you want a visible circle on the screen, but hit-test invisible arcs on that circle?  Yes, you can do that because isPointInStroke does not require that you actually draw the arc to the screen--it only requires that you define that arc (so you would leave off the context.stroke so the arc was defined but "invisible").