# Canvas Drawing and Detection

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i'm trying to make a cricle on canvas. The problem is that the circle is divided in to 4 equal halves each with different color. How can i make those 4 halves in the circle each with a different color? i mean i saw that arc() method only draws only on circle? 
Also that i then want to detect collision on those 4 halves. its easy on the detect on a single color circle but i want to detect which color side of the 1st circle an object (for example another circle on canvas with just one color) collided with e.g. collided with green, blue etc
I can't figure out the how to make the 4 colored circle? help please :/

Comment: i mean i saw that arc() method only draws only one colored circle? **

Answer (score 1):

`context.arc` is a path command.

Path commands start with `context.beginPath` and continue until the next path command (the next path command begins with the next `context.beginPath`).

You are allowed only 1 styling per path command. That means you can't create a multi-colored circle with just 1 path command.

**You will have to use 4 arc path commands to create your 4-colored circle.**

[image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.lineWidth=10;
var cx=150;
var cy=150;
var radius=75;
var PI2=Math.PI*2;
var wedgeCount=4;
var colors=['red','green','gold','blue'];

for(var i=0;i<wedgeCount;i++){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius,PI2/wedgeCount*i,PI2/wedgeCount*(i+1));
  ctx.strokeStyle=colors[i];
  ctx.stroke();
}

function randomColor(){ 
  return('#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

**Collision testing circles made of arcs**

Here is a previous Stackoverflow answer to get you started. It describes how to use angles & distances to calculate if the mouse is over an arc. You can modify it to test for collisions of 2 circles.

[identifying event on arc of circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20218603/identifying-event-on-arc-of-circle/20223482#20223482)

It will simplify your math if you assume each 1/4 circle is a wedge instead of an arc. That way you will not have to eliminate cases where the center points of the 2 circles are so close that the arcs themselves no longer intersect.

First determine if the distance between 2 circles is less than the sum of their radii. If yes, it means *they are possibly but not necessarily intersecting*.

Then connect an imaginary line between the 2 center points and determine the angles of the line. The angles will tell you which wedge(s) are intersecting.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is of great help! Thanks alot!